# I want to init function in Elm

Tags: http, elm

I am trying to pass flags value to Top.elm from Main.elm
and run a function named "getToken" with flags value.
But, it seems like this function "getToken" is not working properly...

My Main.elm is ...

```
type alias Model =
    { key : Nav.Key
    , page : Page
    }


type Page
    = NotFound
    | TopPage ( Page.Top.Model, Cmd Page.Top.Msg )
    | ArticlePage Page.Article.Model


init : String -> Url.Url -> Nav.Key -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags url key =
    Model key (TopPage (Page.Top.init flags))
        |> goTo (Route.parse url)
```

My Top.elm is ...

```
type alias Model =
    { status : LoadingStatus
    }


type LoadingStatus
    = Init
    | Waiting
    | Loaded Token
    | Failed Http.Error


init : String -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init token =
    ( Model Init
    , getToken token )

...

-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = GotToken (Result Http.Error Token)


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        GotToken (Ok token) ->
            ( { model | status = Loaded token }, Cmd.none )

        GotToken (Err err) ->
            ( { model | status = Failed err }, Cmd.none )




-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    case model.status of
            Init ->
                text "sssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"

            Waiting ->
                text "waiting..."

            Loaded token ->
                div []
                    [ p [] [ text "yahoooooooo" ]
                    , p [] [ text token.accessToken ]
                    ]

            Failed e ->
                case e of
                    Http.BadBody message ->
                        pre [] [ text message ]

                    _ ->
                        -- text (Debug.toString e)
                        pre [] [ text "error" ]

...

type alias Token =
    { accessToken : String
    }


-- AccessToken


getToken : String -> Cmd Msg
getToken token =
    Http.request
        { method = "POST"
        , headers =
            [ Http.header "Authorization" ("Bearer " ++ token)
            , Http.header "Accept" "application/json"
            , Http.header "Content-Type" "application/json"
            ]
        , url = "http://localhost:8080/web_users/create"
        , expect = Http.expectJson GotToken tokenDecoder
        , body = Http.emptyBody
        , timeout = Nothing
        , tracker = Nothing
        }


tokenDecoder : Decoder Token
tokenDecoder =
    D.map Token
        (D.field "access_token" D.string)
```

text "sssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" can be seen in a view after the server is launched.
So, it seems like Init in Top.elm is working.
But, it won't go any further.

I assume that getToken function is not working here because I can only see LoadingStatus Init (not Waiting, Loaded, Failed)

Does anybody know why getToken function is not working correctly...??

No error occurs.

Comment: Perhaps the server hangs? What does the browser's debugger say about it?

Comment: Thank you! Actually It hasn’t reached to the server. And browser debugger doesn’t say anything ..

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: have a look in the network tab of the dev console

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the command from your `Top.init` is not getting to the runtime.

I see that you encode the `TopPage ( Page.Top.Model, Cmd Page.Top.Msg )`. This is most likely the culprit. You need something like `TopPage Page.Top.Model` and make sure that the command returned by `Top.init` is joined with the rest of the commands in the `Main.init`

It would look like this:

```
init : String -> Url.Url -> Nav.Key -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags url key =
    let
        ( topModel, topCmd ) =
            Page.Top.init flags

        ( mainModel, mainCmd ) =
            Model key (TopPage topModel)
                |> goTo (Route.parse url)
    in
    ( mainModel, Cmd.batch [ mainCmd, topCmd ] )
```